# Handling concurrency in WCF / Entity Framework with multiple users

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf, concurrency

I have a WCF service that uses `basicHttpBinding` protocol and uses Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server database. Now I need to give multiple users access to the system.

What changes are required in the WCF service level like binding, other protocols to make sure multiple users can efficiently access the application at the same time? How do I make sure concurrency is handled correctly when multiple users edit / update same data?

Comment: WCF by default uses `per-call` instancing - each request gets its own copy of the WCF service implementation class - no concurrency problems here. EF talks to a RDBMS - SQL Server or some other vendor's offering - which should handle concurrency amongst multiple requests, too - so basically, everything *should* be handled for you already

Comment: I have a feeling you're actually talking about handling concurrency *conflicts*.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is already set up for concurrency. Entity framework even uses transactions, by default, for every DbContext.SaveChanges() call. So you're pretty much set up.

That is, unless you do something wrong in your code, of course.